# HTML5 low FPS on Firefox even when rendering just text

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, frame-rate

I'm writing a simple side-scroller in HTML5, just as a side project and to get to grips with HTML5. However, I've been having some FPS issues - Most of them I've resolved simply by optimizing the render code and reducing texture sizes. I'm pretty much at 60 FPS under most circumstances on most browsers... with the exception of Firefox. In the end I sliced away 99% of my code until I'm just rendering only the framerate to the canvas - I still see 25-30 fps under Firefox. I'm thinking I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. I can get 60 fps in Firefox on Microsoft's [Fish Bowl benchmark](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/performance/fishbowl/) with up to 250 fish, so it doesn't appear to be Firefox itself or my system.

My barebones code is as follows (I tried to JSFiddle it, but I don't think it likes HTML5). Note, I realize that since I'm only updating the framerate every second, I shouldn't be rendering the text every frame, but I've left it that way to illustrate the issue.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FPS Demo</title>                     
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="viewport">            
            <canvas id="layer1" width="640" height="480" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                GameLoop();
            };

            // Global vars
            var layer1 = document.getElementById('layer1');
            var context = layer1.getContext('2d');
            var lastLoop = new Date;
            var frameCount = 0;
            var fps = 0;

            // Simple gameloop
            function GameLoop() {
                requestAnimFrame(GameLoop);

                // Calculate FPS
                var thisLoop = new Date;
                if(thisLoop - lastLoop >= 1000) {
                    fps = frameCount;
                    lastLoop = thisLoop;
                    frameCount = 0;
                }
                frameCount++;

                // Render FPS as txt
                context.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 20);    
                context.fillStyle = "black";
                context.fillText("FPS    : " + (fps | 0), 10, 10);                 
            }           

            /**
            * requestAnim shim layer by Paul Irish
            * Finds the first API that works to optimize the animation loop,
            * otherwise defaults to setTimeout().
            */
            window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
                return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element) {
                            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                        };
            })();            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any assistance would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's the rendering of the FPS as text that's slowing down your loop.

Check out this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CbLoc

I replicated your results in Firefox, and then got 60 fps just by moving the rendering of the framerate to only happen when it's calculated.

As for why... I'm not sure. Perhaps Firefox is slow at rendering text on canvas?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, though I should be only rendering the fps text only when it's updated, I left it that way to show the problem - As soon as I render anything that needs to be done every frame(text, sprites, whatever), Firefox drops back down to 25-30 fps, whilst all other browsers I've tested stay happily at 60 fps.